# How to prevent duplicate values in enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I wonder is there a way to prevent an `enum` with duplicate keys to compile?

For instance this `enum` below will compile

```
public enum EDuplicates
{
    Unique,
    Duplicate = 0,
    Keys = 1,
    Compilation = 1
}
```

Although this code

```
Console.WriteLine(EDuplicates.Unique);
Console.WriteLine(EDuplicates.Duplicate);
Console.WriteLine(EDuplicates.Keys);
Console.WriteLine(EDuplicates.Compilation);
```

Will print

```
Duplicate
Duplicate
Keys
Keys
```

Comment: Ah the joys of Java enums. :)

Comment: See the following link to know why `Console.WriteLine(EDuplicates.Unique);` prints `Duplicate` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530281/unexpected-result-when-using-enum-parse

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This isn't prohibited by the language specification, so any conformant C# compiler *should* allow it. You could always adapt the Mono compiler to forbid it - but frankly it would be simpler to write a unit test to scan your assemblies for enums and enforce it that way.

Comment: I'm probably missing the point here: What is the useful scenario for supporting this? If there are no useful scenarios why would you prefer writing unit tests for this over letting the compiler handle the situation?

Comment: @Brian: To avoid breaking existing code. Backwards compatibility is important, as is conforming with the spec. I can't immediately think of any useful scenarios, but that doesn't mean I would want to break anyone who is using this already.

Comment: @Brian: It can be useful if you for some reason wish to change the name of an enum value without breaking old code: add a new value with the new name and the same numeric value as the old one, and decorate the old value with the `Obsolete` attribute.

Comment: I had discovered this problem (duplicate keys) while writing unit test for semi-autogenerated enums. It was an unpleasant surprise, so I got myself interested is there a way to ensure this somehow. I was thinking of an Attribute or compiler flag or something like that.

Comment: wouldn't also be useful for providing several alternate names for the same thing? (like "Ace" and "HighestFaceCard"). Or is that an anti-pattern?

Comment: Yes, obviously, the whole build could be set up to break on unit test break so using unit test is quite enough, I have overlooked this before.

Comment: Another option which some people like is to have a "MinimumValue" and "MaximumValue". I'm not terribly fond of it myself...

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: In objects which have lots of instances, enums can help pack multiple bits of information in minimal space, a small step up from C-style bit-packing in ints. See for example System.Reflection.MethodAttributes where they have VtableLayoutMask=256 to bit test whether the method will take a NewSlot=256 or ReuseSlot=0. We might see `if ((m.Attributes & MethodAttributes.VtableLayoutMask) == MethodAttributes.NewSlot)` to test if the method takes a new vtable slot. And 0 (ReuseSlot) is also the accessibility value PrivateScope (representing a method only callable by the compiler).

Answer (score 35):

Here's a simple unit test that checks it, should be a bit faster:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
  var enums = (myEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum));
  Assert.IsTrue(enums.Count() == enums.Distinct().Count());
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Unit test that checks enum and shows which particular enum values has duplicates:

```
[Fact]
public void MyEnumTest()
{
    var values = (MyEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
    var duplicateValues = values.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();
    Assert.True(duplicateValues.Length == 0, "MyEnum has duplicate values for: " + string.Join(", ", duplicateValues));
}
```

Comment: Should be Assert.IsTrue.

Comment: [Fact] and Assert.True are for xUnit testing framework.

Answer (score 2):

Just as addition, if you want to test ALL enums inside your project:

```
   [Test]
    public void EnumsDoNotHaveDuplicates()
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> enums = typeof(MyEnum).Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsEnum && t.IsPublic);

        foreach (Type t in enums)
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(EnumTestFixture).GetMethod(nameof(VerifyEnumHasNoDuplicates));
            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);
            generic.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }

    public void VerifyEnumHasNoDuplicates<T>()
    {
        T[] values = (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        Assert.IsTrue(values.Count() == values.Distinct().Count(), $"{typeof(T).Name} has duplicates!");
    }
```

Replace `MyEnum` with the any `Type` in the assembly that should be tested.

If you don't like the approach with Reflection or you prefer to have a test per enum (for whatever reason) you can still use the generic method:

`VerifyEnumHasNoDuplicates<MyEnum>()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool ValidateAllDistinct(Type enumType)
{
    return !Enum.GetNames(enumType).All(outerName
        => Enum.GetNames(enumType).Any(innerName
            => innerName == outerName 
                ? true 
                : Enum.Parse(enumType, innerName) != Enum.Parse(enumType, outerName)));
}
```

I simple test method for your unittest.

Comment: This is something like the unit test I had had to write with only difference my is printing duplicate keys.

Comment: Accordning to [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0KoChn) fiddle it does not work. Please correct me if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

another solution to have unique values based on selected columns

```
var uniqueData = temp.Select(u => new tblschClassSchedule
            {
                TeacherName = u.TeacherName,
                SubjectName = u.SubjectName,

            }).Distinct() ;
```

this will get only 2 columns and only unique data for those columns