# Can you have multiple enum values for the same integer?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, clr

In `.NET` can you have multiple `enum` values for the same integer?

eg.

```
public enum PersonGender
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Male = 1,
        Female = 2,
        Intersex = 3,
        Indeterminate = 3,
        NonStated = 9,
        InadequatelyDescribed = 9
    }
```

Comment: What did the compiler say when you tried it? Seriously, does no-one ever _think_ anymore?

Comment: @paxdiablo In C++ a lot of undefined behavior will be accepted by compilers without warning.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, this isn't C++, it's C#. The behaviour is defined by MS.

Comment: I'm curious to know, what is your underlying purpose in this?  Obviously, what you say want is illogical; however, it doesn't seem like you would ask a question whose ultimate purpose makes no sense.

Comment: @paxdiablo The question is tagged VB .NET

Comment: @ta.speot.is Which is also not C++. He is probably more interested in whether this works in CLR languages.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: and, on top of that, it's _also_ tagged c#, and the code isn't vb, not by a long stretch :-)

Comment: @GeorgeWBush I cant see the link, but if you say so I will take more care, OP post [another duplicate shortly before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458257/how-to-have-enum-values-with-spaces). Guess I jumped to conclusion.

Answer (score 23):

In C#, this is allowed, as per the [C# Language Specication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), version 4. Section `1.10 Enums` doesn't *explicitly* mention the possibility but, later on in section `14 Enums, 14.3`, we see:

> Multiple `enum` members may share the same associated value. The example
>
> ```
> enum Color {
>    Red,
>    Green,
>    Blue,
>    Max = Blue
> }
> ```
>
> shows an `enum` in which two `enum` members - `Blue` and `Max` - have the same associated value.

Comment: Interestingly, if you have the code analyzer [CA1069](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1069?view=vs-2019) enabled, the above is fine, but if you assigned `Max = 2` then the analyzer will complain about assigning the same constant value

Comment: @David, it's probably assuming that, if you assign a *constant* to two different enum values, there's a non-zero chance that you may have made a mistake, especially if the values are all over the place: `enum x { a = 42, b = 17, c = 12, d = 314159, e = 271828, f = 17 };`. If you assign an already-existing *enum value* to an enum value, it's probably safe to assume you *meant* to do that.

Comment: I think you're right. It's not a bad way of checking you're doing the right thing

Answer (score 4):

That works fine. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code you posted. It compiles just fine and works in code, with the caveat that

```
PersonGender.NonStated == PersonGender.InadequatelyDescribed
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this StackOverflow post related to this question. I think there is a very sensible discussion of how this works. [Non-unique enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043027/non-unique-enum-values)

Now, I might also add that it is my opinion this would be an ambiguous (and therefore improper) use of an enum.  It's important to write code that makes sense to someone else reading it, and in this case, I would be put off by this enum.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that an **enum** would not be a right thing to use in your context instead you can use create a class and methods which can resolve your purpose. Something like this in your class:-

```
class A
{

    static readonly ABCD= new Dictionary<int,string>
        {
            { 1, "X" },
            { 2, "X" },
            { 3, "Y" }
            { 4, "Y" }
        }
}
```

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta:- Yes I agree that I should not give it is as a conclusion but definitely thats my suggestion.