# How to have enum values with spaces?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums

How can I achieve the following using enums in `.NET`?  I would like to have descriptions for each value that include spaces.

```
public enum PersonGender
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Male = 1,
        Female = 2,
        Intersex = 3,
        Indeterminate = 3,
        Non Stated = 9,
        Inadequately Described = 9
    }
```

I would like to be able to choose whether to use either the description or integer each time I use a value of this type.

Comment: Related answer on another post - [Can my enums have friendly names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415460/465053)

Answer (score 54):

No that's not possible, but you can attach attributes to `enum` members. The [`EnumMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute.aspx) is designed exactly for the purpose you described.

```
public enum PersonGender
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
    Intersex = 3,
    Indeterminate = 3,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Not Stated")]
    NonStated = 9,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Inadequately Described")]
    InadequatelyDescribed = 9
}
```

For more information on how to use the `EnumMemberAttribute` to convert strings to `enum` values, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418651/using-enummemberattribute-and-doing-automatic-string-conversions).

Comment: Can a `DescriptionAttribute` be used?

Comment: Yes it can. In fact, any attribute class that has `AttributeTargets.Field` or `AttributeTargets.All` can be used. You can also write your own. Here are examples using [`DesciptionAttribute`](http://tinyurl.com/clqr3ht) and a [custom attribute](http://tinyurl.com/cyd2b6q).

Comment: +1 Very clear.  I have a question though.  I get `The type or namespace name 'EnumMember' could not be found ...`  How does it get included in one's project?  After a Google search, I found 3 results and none of them addressed the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see, first I have to include `System.Runtime.Serialization` as a resource in my project and then put a using statement in the file

Comment: @p.s.w.g I guess my project doesn't have the assembly or reference added. What's the reference lib for this?

Comment: @bonCodigo For any class reference you find on MSDN, there's a namespace and assembly listed just above the syntax. The assembly is what you need to add to your project as a reference, and the namespace is what you need to add at the top of your file as a `using` directive. In this case, both are `System.Runtime.Serialization`

Comment: @p.s.w.g I found it and added, however still at the same slogged phase. It is just not recognizing the darn `enummember...` or `description`

Comment: @bonCodigo Perhaps you need to clean your solution and rebuild. See [Building and Cleaning Projects and Solutions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx)

Comment: add reference System.Runtime.Serialization to project

Answer (score 5):

This is easy. Create an extension method for your string that returns a formatted string based on your coding convention.  You can use it in lots of places, not just here. This one works for camelCase and TitleCase.

```
    public static String ToLabelFormat(this String s)
    {
        var newStr = Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])", " ");
        newStr = Regex.Replace(newStr, "(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])", " ");
        newStr = Regex.Replace(newStr, "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])", " ");

        return newStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ResourcesLib.DLL");            
var resourceManager =
new ResourceManager("ResourcesLib.EnumDescriptions", assembly);                        

var lst = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PersonGender)).Cast<PersonGender>().ToList();
foreach (var gender in lst)
{
  Console.WriteLine(gender); // Name
  Console.WriteLine((int)gender); //Int Value
  Console.WriteLine(resourceManager.GetString(gender.ToString()));//localized Resorce
}
```

So spaces may reside in localized resource ...