# C# enums - Possible to have double ids

Tags: c#, .net, enums, unique

I just noticed that you can create something like this in C#:

```
enum TestEnum
{
  First = 1,
  Second = 1,
  Third = 2
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
  TestEnum test = TestEnum.First;
  var en = (TestEnum) 1;//And en is now set to First
}
```

We would like the enums value to be unique. Right now, I have written a unit test that checks that each value is only used once in our enum. Is there a better way to force the uniqueness?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8043127/1714342 and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8043148/1714342

Comment: Because it isn't part of the specs.  Also, you can do this:  `var whatisthisidonteven = (TestEnum)4;` Now, which enum value is that??

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll have a look. And changed my question a bit to remove the first part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Well enums are used to give meaning to integers. When you say Second = 1 that doesn't make sense but think of an example like that one:

```
enum HumanEnum
{
    Man = 1,
    Woman = 0,
    Lady = 0,
    Boy = 1,
    Girl = 0
}
```

Let's say 0 and 1 represents the gender, in this way Man and Boy has the same gender value.

Comment: Before downvoters - Original question asked why can enums have same values, doesnt suit new edit though

Comment: Ok, I suppose it makes sense in some cases to have multiple enum values with the same id.

Comment: It also works to define `Man = 1, Woman = 0, Lady = Woman, Boy = Man, Girl = Woman`.