# get string value from enum

Tags: c#, .net

I have enum defined as below

```
public enum PatientRaceCodeType
{
    [StringValue("Question not asked")] 
    Q = 8,
    [StringValue("Unknown")]
    U = Q | B,
    [StringValue("Native Hawaiian OR Other Pacific Islander")]
    P = Q | D,
}
```

I need to get the string value for example if `U` it should return "unknown"

tried this:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(testRaceCodeType), test.RaceCode)
```

which is not working. `test.Racecode` has value `U`

Comment: What are  `B` and  `D`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23284598/2721713) answer. I think this is what you want.

Comment: I would go with Type safe enums, as detailed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/424414/1395758

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me
 (testRaceCodeType) Enum.Parse(typeof (testRaceCodeType), test.RaceCode))
                                .GetStringValue()