# Error when mapping enum with a value defined twice with ConvertUsingEnumMapping

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map an enum value to another using

```
CreateMap<Enum1, Enum2>()
                .ConvertUsingEnumMapping(m => m.MapByName())
                .ReverseMap();
```

The enums are like this

```
 public enum Enum1
    {
        action1 = 1,
        action2 = 2
        aliasAction1 = 1
    }

 public enum Enum2
    {
        action1 = 1,
        action2 = 2
        aliasAction1 = 1
    }
```

When running the mapping validation test using

```
configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

I get an error regarding the enum value key already exists. Even though I am doing mapping by name instead of by value.
Specifically

```
System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Is there any way to perform this mapping without doing it manually myself?

**EDIT** Extra info to avoid a possible hail-storm

I understand that non-unique enum values are to be frowned upon and avoided at all costs, but, the enum is provided from a third party that I need to convert to proto for internal use, thus the need for mapping using Automapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible and it's not AutoMapper's fault.

If you try to map it manually without AutoMapper it would more or less look like these few lines below. A switch, leading from one enum to another.

```
public Enum2 Convert(Enum1 source)
{
    switch (source)
    {
        case Enum1.action1:
            return Enum2.action1;
        case Enum1.action2:
            return Enum2.action2;
        case Enum1.aliasAction1:
            return Enum2.aliasAction1;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

But wait... the compiler seems to have a problem with the case for `aliasAction1`:

```
case Enum1.aliasAction1:
    return Enum2.aliasAction1;
```

> CS0152: The switch statement contains multiple cases with the label value '1'

It's because the switch statement already defines a path for value `1`, which is `action1`. Even if the compiler allowed you to write such switch, the case for `aliasAction1` would be unreachable, because the case for value `1` is already defined earlier, thus all enum members with value `1` would fall right in the first case.

Let's declare a variable for `Enum1` and set its value to `aliasAction1`:

```
var enumValue = Enum1.aliasAction1;
Console.WriteLine(enumValue);
```

and the output will be:

```
action1
```

Compiler selects first value arbitrarily. Here is a great answer on [non-unique enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043027/non-unique-enum-values).

And when it comes to solution to your problem, I'd suggest creating a struct that will act as non-unique enum.

However, if you are aware and okay with non-unique enum members and simply want the mapping to work, then all you have to do is remove the `CreateMap()` because enum mapping work with AutoMapper by convention without any explicit configuration (as long as the names/values match).

Comment: The enum is provided by a third-party that I need to convert to a proto class for internal use, so avoiding non-unique enums is out of the question. But I appreciate your help