# C# forbid duplicate Enum values

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums

Is there a way to forbid duplicate Enum values in C# or VB.NET, so that the compiler can not run?

Somthing like that:

```
[NoDuplicateEnumValues]
enum Importance
{
    None      = 0,
    Trivial   = 2,
    Regular   = 3,
    Important = 3,   //<-- compiler error
    Critical  = 4
};
```

Comment: No. (But it is unacceptable answer on SO as it is too short).

Comment: You need a test suite! No such compile time error exist.

Comment: You could create a unit test to check all your enums.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425777/how-to-prevent-duplicate-values-in-enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425777/how-to-prevent-duplicate-values-in-enum)

Comment: This isn't an error so why would you want to prevent it? If it's because of a mistake, well, there are millions of mistakes programmers can make, we call them bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will create a Unit Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no ways to do it.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why one voted correct answer down... Really not much to say (even Jon Skeet's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1425791/477420) is essentially the same).